# Whitespace after last row on .NET DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am working with a datagridview in c#, when the datagridview contains as many rows to fill the size and show a vertical scrollbar and I scroll down to the last row, there's an whitespace with the height of a row.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the datagridview, is there possibly a footer thats taking up space but doesn't have anything in it?

Comment: I think the DataGridView doesn't support footers, I did a quick google search and found some people asking how to add a footer and the replies involved creating an user control that inherits the DataGridView control.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and setting the background color is not an option for me. Cause I have to add another DataGridView right to the bottom of this one.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old post but I came here looking for a solution and ended up figuring out my problem.
Basically, the height of the DataControlView has to be an exact multiple of the number of rows displayed. All I had to do is increase the view height in the designer by a couple of pixels and the blank row disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a Grid has an extra row related to editing.  For example, DataGridView has the EditMode property.  If you set this to a value indicating that the view is not editable by the user, that might make the row at the bottom disappear.

Comment: But EditMode cannot be set to any value that indicates the datagridview is not editable, ReadOnly bool do that, EditMode sets the way you enter the "edit mode" (EditOnEnter, EditOnKeystroke, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Probably your grid back color is white. Please change it.

Answer (score 0):

```
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

My first guess would be that you have a footer row with nothing in it. Try setting ShowFooter="false" on your grid view.

Comment: My DataGridView doesn't have a "ShowFooter" property.

Answer (score -1):

tryout to set the

> AllowUserToAddRows

property to false